# The error size of discrete approximation to a optimal control problem

Tags: optimization, control-theory, optimal-control

I'm considering an optimal control problem of form $$M=\underset{p(k)\in [0,V]}{\max}\int_{k\in K} p(k)h(k)\ dk,$$ where $h(k)$ is a given function and $p(k)$ must be (weakly) decreasing. I know that if $h(k)$ is also decreasing, then the bang-bang principle gives the optimal solution.

However, I am curious about the case where $h(k)$ is not decreasing. If we restrict to a decreasing step functions $p(k)=p_n (k)$ which at most takes $n$ different values. How well would $$M_n=\underset{p_n(k)\in [0,V]}{\max}\int_{k\in K} p_n(k)h(k)\ dk$$ approximate $M$? How would I approach this problem, and what role does $h(k)$ play here?

Comment: Maybe I'm confused, if $h>0$ then isn't the maximum always just attained with $p \equiv V$? Or is there some additional condition on $p$?

Comment: Oh, sorry it is $p>0$, not $h$.

Comment: So $h$ might change sign more than once if it isn't monotone, but $p$ needs to be monotone decreasing, so there is a tradeoff between dropping $p$ by a lot when $h$ becomes negative vs. being unable to raise it back up when $h$ becomes positive again. Right?

Comment: Yes. If I understand correctly, $M$ can be derived from the Pontryagin method by setting a Lagrangian type of constraint for $p^\prime (k)\leq 0$. But I don't know how or if this related to the stepwise function.